# Is it possible to detect :visited URL with canonical URL?

Tags: html, canonical-link, visited

As title, I'm thinking of is it possible to tell browser that after user visited a page with URL `https://example.com/somepath?q=somequery` and with a canonical URL tag `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/somepath" />`, then this link `<a href="https://example.com/somepath"></a>` is set to `:visited`?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the wording, but feel this is a good question. Is it this: After a user visited a page with a canonical URL tag, all other links to that same canonical URL should display as visited?

Comment: Using a server side language you can do so

Comment: You could try `history.replaceState({}, {}, '[canonicalURl]')` on the visited page.

Comment: @Marcel Yes you're right!

Comment: @M0ns1f But it also change the behavior of next/prev page buttons on browser.